# Android blank space animation

Tags: android, animation

I try to hide the HEADER layout when I scroll on a recyclerview. In order to hide the layout I use an animation in the "onScrolled" event :

-Show :

```
layout.animate().translationY(-layout.getHeight()).setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(2));
```

-Hide :

```
layout.animate().translationY(0).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));
```

It's working in a way but I've still got a blank space where the HEADER was.

liste_view_layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">

   <!-- HEADER -->
   <include layout="@layout/header_list_view" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <include layout="@layout/common_recyclerview_layout"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

header_list_view :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/header_list_view_layout_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
>
  <TopBarHeaderView
  android:id="@+id/header_list_view_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">
       <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/subcategory_header_section"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <include layout="@layout/header_section"/>
       </FrameLayout>
    </TopBarHeaderView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Example layout :]

Answer (score 1):

Animations changes the way the view is drawn, but its true location still remains the same. So while it looks like the header moved or was hidden, it's still technically there.

To solve this you can either:

Set `animation.setFillAfter(true);`

or

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        //set view visibility to `GONE`
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Comment: When the animation is played, the Header container does not follow the content. The container keeps the same height rather than progressively decreasing it.

Comment: Maybe have another animation playing for the container also?

Comment: I use the following layout for the animation : header_list_view with ID : header_list_view_layout_container. I playing the animation on the container